# Is there a way to override locale data?

Tags: localization, configuration

We are using the Craft's currency filter to display localised prices `344552.32 | currency('GBP')` which works great in most instances.

However the currency symbol for UK Sterling in the French locale file is `£UK` and the translation company we are working with are saying that we just need to output `£`.

This is defined in the `currencySymbols` array of `craft/app/framework/i18n/data.fr.php`.

Is there a way we can affect that at a configuration level or at runtime? If not I guess we would have to create our own filter function that wraps the core functionality and does a string replace on the output.

Answer (score 1):

A further requirement came up to change the Italian output (symbol moved to *after* the price rather than *before*) so I opted for a simple Twig extension:

```
/**
 * Wrapper for Craft's NumberFormatter->formatCurrency
 * Changes formats for French and Italian display
 *
 * @param        $value
 * @param string $currency
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function currencyDisplay ($value, $currency = 'GBP')
{
    $value = craft()->numberFormatter->formatCurrency($value, $currency);
    $localeId = craft()->locale->id;

    if ($localeId == 'fr')
    {
        $value = str_replace('£UK', '£', $value); // remove UK
    }
    else if ($localeId == 'it')
    {
        $value = str_replace('£ ', '', $value) . ' £'; // relocate sterling symbol
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can override that, but I'm not 100% sure. But, there's always the option to run the `replace`filter on the output from `currency`:

```
{{ 344552.32 | currency('GBP') | replace('£UK', '£') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

A plugin like you mention is an option, but you should be able to use [static translations](https://craftcms.com/support/static-translations) for this, too.  Only downside is that it would replace *all* instances of `£UK` with `£`, which may or may not be a problem.